# How to pop up a figure and wait response

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent

I am writing a python loop where a figure is pop up, and i save the coordinates, then do some calculations. My questions are:
1- How can I stop the loop until I get my mouse press and store coordinates?
2- How can I store the coordinates in a variable, not printing?
3- How can I close figure with same event?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('button_press_event', callback)

def callback(event):
    return event.xdata, event.ydata
    

for i in range(3):
    
    print('before')
    ax.plot(np.arange(1,11,1), np.arange(50,60,1))
    
    # how to wait for mouse click
    # How to save in variable
    coordinates = get event.xdata, event.ydata  #??
    
    "then proceed the loop"
    # do any calculations using event.xdata, event.ydata
```

Comment: Specifically, you just want 3 loops ?

Comment: No, just one loop, pop up figure, then, press click to get x,y, after that save x,y, and continue loop

Comment: Hi, I have added an answer, hopefully this is the function you need.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said only one loop and you wanted a pup-up figure. In fact, the pop-up of figure is not a must for your usage. You can use two subplots, one for plotting the original data, the other one for presenting new "pop-up" figure. But you have to write it in python class. Here is some demo code for you:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Demo:
    
    def __init__(self, fig, x, y):
        self.fig = fig
        self.ax1 = fig.axes[0]
        self.ax2 = fig.axes[1]
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
        self.ax1.plot(x, y)
        
        self.click = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.onclick)
        
    def onclick(self, event):
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        print(x, y)
        # do calculation here, plot another figure here
        # get the distance to point (x, y)
        d = np.sqrt((self.x-x)**2+(self.y-y)**2)
        # plot d in second ax
        if len(self.ax2.lines) != 0:
            self.ax2.lines = []
            self.ax2.plot(d)
        else:
            self.ax2.plot(d)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        
        
x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 256)
y = np.sin(x)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(7.2, 7.2/2))
app = Demo(fig, x, y)
```

Try to click on ax on the left, see how things change in ax on the the right. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your share. I still have a problem in how to pause the loop till i pick event and close figure

Comment: I guess you need to frame your question in more details, otherwise it's abit general.